About barium titanate
Is barium titanate (BaTiO3) thin film martensite? Recently, Everhardt et al., in PRL (123, 087603 (2019)), show that as temperature increases, the domain evolution shows period-doubling bifurcation accompanies structural change as well.

By default,- no. But it can be prepared in that state by diffusionless transformation.
